# Serialize php class to xsd

Tags: php, xsd

I want to build XSD files for my webservice, so other developers can easily work with it and generate their model classes from my XSD files.

I only find tools to generate PHP from XSD, but nothing to inverse.

How I can serialize my php model classes to XSD programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint with the SDK XML Data Access Service ...

Got an idea while reading the manual :-)

I now write a XML File saving each Request and Response XML in a XML File.
Then I generate a XSD File from the XML File via xsd.exe delivered by Microsoft Visual Studio.
Then I edit the Datatype Properties in each XSD files ...

A bit of work, but better than writing the XSD files by hand